# Dropping a file onto a python script in windows - avoid Windows use of backslashes in the argument

Tags: python, windows, path, operating-system, backslash

I know all about how Windows uses backslashes for filenames, etc., and Unix uses forward. However, I never use backslashes with strings I create in my code. However:

When windows explorer "drops" a file onto a python script, the string it passes contains backslashes. These translate into escape sequences in the strings in the sys.argv list and then I have no way to change them after that (open to suggestions there)

Is there any way I can somehow make windows pass a literal string or ... any other way I can solve this problem?

I'd love my script to be droppable, but the only thing preventing me is windows backslashes.

EDIT:

Sorry everyone, the error was actually not the passing of the string - as someone has pointed out below, but this could still help someone else:

Make sure you use absolute path names because when the Windows shell will NOT run the script in the current directory as you would from a command line. This causes permission denied errors when attempting to write to single-part path-names that aren't absolute.

Comment: What makes you think that the backslashes are getting translated into escape sequences?  Are you sure that it's not just the interpreter escaping them when printing them out for your convenience?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855477/how-to-access-sys-argv-or-any-string-variable-in-raw-mode

Comment: I'd go with not a duplicate, just a misinterpreted error on the OP's part.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce. This:

```
import os, sys
print sys.argv
print map(os.path.exists, sys.argv)
raw_input()
```

gives me this:

```
['D:\\workspaces\\generic\\SO_Python\\9266551.py', 'D:\\workspaces\\generic\\SO_Python\\9254991.py']
[True, True]
```

after dropping the second file onto the first one. Python 2.7.2 (on Windows). Can you try this code out?

Comment: You're correct, I've solved the underlying problem and posted the solution above.

Comment: Hmm, it would be better if you created an answer of your own then, and accepted it, otherwise the question will remain unanswered, when it is in fact answered... Btw, sys.argv[0] is already the absolute path of your script, using that you can calculate all your absolute paths and avoid hard-coding the paths in your script.